# Unable to display favicon on any browser tab

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I pointed to favicon.ico file, as shown below, which is present in my local project folder. But, on the browser tab it is not displaying rather displaying a blurred image.

My favicon in present in a jar file. Hence, I used `<c:url/>` for path by adding `<mvc:resources/>` in my spring context file.

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/img/favicon.ico" />" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Can someone tell me where it is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/resources/img/favicon.ico" />
```

Make sure you are putting correct 
path in href field.

Comment: My favicon is present in a jar file. Updated my query too.